# How to access a function defined in a ui-router state controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular ui-router state with a controller as follows.

```
 $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.title="MyTitle";
    $scope.myFunction= function(){
         //do something
    };
  },
  data:{
     list:[
            {
              item:"item1",
              callback:{{myFunction}}
            }
          ]
  }
})
```

As shown in the code above, the state controller has a function attached to the scope called "myFunction".
I also have a directive which accesses this state. In that directive, I want to call the myFunction as callback when item1 is clicked(i have a button corresponding to item1 mentioned in data section).
Please let me know how i can call the myFunction method from my directive.